# User profiles confused

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, userprofilemanager

SharePoint 2016 Enterprise, Integrated Windows Authentication. I have a user that logs into SharePoint with the same account as she logs into her computer as. When she navigates to some pages her name in the upper right hand corner changes to a different users name. This is further seen when she attempts to fill in an InfoPath form that looks up the username from the user profile service.

Using the "Get-SPUSer" command everything appears to be just fine however when I use the GetUserProfile method on the profile manager I see that it is messed up.
Basic script:

```
    $siteURL = "SUTEURL"
$site = get-spsite $siteURL
$context = Get-SpServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$prof = $ProfileManager.GetUserProfile("USERID")
$prof
```

If I user userA for the UserID, I get profile for **USERA**. If I user UserB for USerID I get profile for **USERA**. So I was thinking that the profile was just messed up and I will delete it from the user profile service, however UserB does not have a profile in the user profile service at all. (I did also put in another account to confirm my testing process worked and it returned correct information).

I have confirmed that all AD information is correct and that the accounts are not connected at all. All information and thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reverse proxy or load balancer in front of SharePoint?

Comment: No there is not. I was thinking about device caching too, but it is only these two users and always these two users.

Comment: Have you looked at sIDhistory in ADSIedit?

Comment: Yes, SID's are unique and sIDHistory is "not set".

Comment: Remove that user from user information list UIL and log in again with that user to get new id in UIL. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e816a0c5-7e85-4aa9-aa41-d6b98d6afb17/cannot-delete-user-from-hidden-user-information-list?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: I believe I tried this at one time, but will look at it again. Removing the user from the User Information Table does not truly "remove" the user. It is still store in the database table and marked for delete in order to maintain the user ID that is used for all references. When the user is "found" again, it will just activate the old ID again. If there is a way to actually "remove" the user completely, all references (last modified by, created by, etc) would then be broken. I would need to test this before I put in production

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever changed the user name for the user?

Please remove the user from the SharePoint and grant permission to the user and compare the results.

Navifate to http://yoursite/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0, remove the user from the site.

Besides, here is an article for your reference:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/user-login-name-changed-in-ad-how-to-sync-with-sharepoint.html

Comment: nope, User login name was never changed. they have always been two completely different accounts. I did however find that they are no patched correctly right now. Mismatch on patching between the servers. I remember that Ignite, Spence Harbar had talked about an issue of "managers" not updating correctly being fixed at a certain patch level. They are experiencing that too, so I am having them patch the entire system to the most recent update before looking into it further.